# Xamarin : How to invoke IValueConverter on a notification call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter

I have got a Listview(which is tied to an ObservableCollection), all the elements do Enable/Disable calculation based on a IValueConverter.

Below is the code for IValueConverter...

```
public class StateCheckConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = false;

            if (value != null)
            {
                var element = value as Element;
                if (element.Status != Status.Pending)
                    result = true;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Now I have got a notification(from MessageCenter) and on the call back state of one of the element has changed. Im able to change the text and values of the element(say label, image using INotifyPropertyChanged). But how do I invoke the corresponding IValueConverter and update the ObservableCollection?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:StateCheckConverter x:Key="transmissionStateCheck" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

---

```
<Label x:Name="lblLocked"
                         IsVisible="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource transmissionStateCheck}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                         BackgroundColor="Gray"
                         Opacity="0.75"
                         Text="LOCKED"
                         TextColor="White"
                         FontSize="35"
                         />
```

Comment: How do you use the converter? Please post the code where you bind the `IsEnabled` state of the items.

Comment: @Emad I have updated the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok one way is to change you binding property and bind to the `Status` itself:

```
<Label x:Name="lblLocked"
       IsVisible="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource transmissionStateCheck}}"
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
       BackgroundColor="Gray"
       Opacity="0.75"
       Text="LOCKED"
       TextColor="White"
       FontSize="35"/>
```

Of course you will then have to change your value converter as well:

```
public class StateCheckConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (value is Status status)
        {
            if (status != Status.Pending)
                result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Also I have changed a few things in your code. You can't bind `IsVisible` with two way mode so it will automatically be one way.

Also convert back should take `bool` and return `Status` which is impossible and unnecessary so I removed it.

Comment: Works perfectly, +1 for the way you have dug in :)